# microphone not working with chrome browser

Tags: sound, google-chrome, microphone

The chrome browser stopped working with my microphone, I'm using multiple chrome profiles and it stopped on all profiles. there are no error messages that I can see.
this is not a permission issue and the mic works well with firefox and other application.
I think that it started after enabling JBL Bluetooth earbuds.
any idea how to debug this issue?

versions:
ubuntu 22.04
chrome: 109.0.5414.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
pactl info 
Server String: /run/user/1001/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 234
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: XXXX
Host Name: XXXX-XXX
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.63)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
Cookie: 3646:fc8c
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was an issue with my user profile, deleting `${HOME}/.locat` and restart resolve my problem